ROS2, Gazebo, Gym, /reset_simulation service hangs script
I am trying to use Gazebo to train a robot in simulation, but I am unable to reset the Gazebo world. This was previously working, but after some fiddling around with other tests in a different environment and coming back to this one, things have seem to have broken.
I am setting up the ROS2 node inside my custom Gym environment in this way:
rclpy.init()
self.node = rclpy.create_node(self.__class__.__name__)
self._pub_vel = self.node.create_publisher(Twist, '/cmd_vel', 10) 
self._sub_odom = self.node.create_subscription(Odometry, '/odom', self._odom_callback, 10) 
self._sub_lidar = self.node.create_subscription(LaserScan, '/scan', self._lidar_callback, 10) 
self.reset_sim = self.node.create_client(Empty, '/reset_simulation')

I believe that this is correct.
However, when I run this and try to reset the simulation with this code block:
# request a reset
reset_future = self.reset_sim.call_async(Empty.Request())
# wait until reset is finished
rclpy.spin_until_future_complete(self.node, reset_future)

The script hangs on spin_until_future_complete(). The service is present in 'ros2 service list'.
...
/laser_controller/set_parameters
/laser_controller/set_parameters_atomically
/pause_physics
/reset_simulation
/reset_world
/robot_state_publisher/describe_parameters
/robot_state_publisher/get_parameter_types
...

Currently using these versions:
Gazebo 11
ROS2 Foxy
Gymnasium latest

Removing the update rate of my LiDAR sensor in my URDF file fixed the issue.
